# Can no longer access Google Apps services through external applications

Tags: google-workspace

I should note that I also recently transitioned my account to a full Google account. I'm not positive that transitioning my Google Apps account to a full account is the root of the cause here, but it's been quite a bit of hassle since I made that move.

About a week ago I was simultaneously no longer able to login to my Gchat through Adium, Pidgin (on a different machine), and mail/calendars on my iPod Touch (which is configured as an Exchange account).

Things that have not worked are the CAPTCHA unlock, resetting the password, re-adding the accounts... Double checked the configs on everything and I have a parallel non-transitioned Apps account accessing these services on the same machines, with identical configs, perfectly normally.

Sort of at a loss as to what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. It looks like there's some sort of clash between the two accounts that causes non-web logins (IMAP, Talk) to fail. What I did was to carefully go through my now-renamed consumer account (@gtempaccounts.com) and move my data across, and then close down the consumer account. After that things started working again.

I haven't yet thought the whole thing through but I will be reporting something to Google next week as this will likely hurt our organisation when the time comes to transition our domains.